# Testing AccountController in .NETCore 2

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

thanks in advance for your time. I'm a student and we have to unit test our Asp.net core 2 Web App. The app has authentication and we have to test the account controller. I've tried a bunch of stuff but I can't even instantiate the controller.

My account controller has the following constructor:

```
public AccountController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        IEmailSender emailSender,
        ILogger<AccountController> logger,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _logger = logger;
        _rolemanager = roleManager;
        _context = context;
    }
```

Method being tested:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result =
                await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.NumeroInterno, model.Password, model.RememberMe,
                    false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Tentativa de Login inválida (dados incorretos).");
            return View(model);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: we need to see your current test in order to better diagnose the issue.

Comment: have you tried? `var x = new AccountController();`

Comment: Hi, I just need to test the default login in MVC web App

Comment: Thanks @Malachi but if I use only that code, i'll not be able to login a user.

Comment: obviously you need to pass in the correct parameters. then once you have an object created, you will need to call the correct method to log in the user

Comment: @Malachi but I have a different project for testing. I don't know how to pass, for example the rolemanager from my Web App project to my UnitTestProject

Comment: @RuiBorges If you are unit testing then create the test, mock the necessary dependencies and inject them into the class under test then invoke the method under test and verify the expected behavior.

Comment: @RuiBorges show the method under test. That would be the method you would expect called when logging in.

Comment: You will probably want some test helpers to create these dependent objects in your test project.  Outside the context of this particular assignment, you will probably need many of the same objects to test other controllers, or other functionalities of the same controller.  You would not pass any objects used in the app to the tests, instead make new ones used for testing in the test project.

Comment: Hey @Nkosi I've added the method

Comment: @RuiBorges, right, standard template. You can use a mocking framework to mock the necessary dependencies for that method. looks like it only needs the sign in manager and the logger.